# aspnetboilerplate global user table (common for all tenants)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Let's assume below scenario.

There can be multiple tenants. Each tenant offers different services based on their business to clients. Depending on the size of the client, they may have their own database as well (ex:- Large clients prefer their data to be isolated).

Arranging tenants to fulfill above scenario is possible with the AspNetBoilerplate out of the box.

Then comes the customers who consumes various services provided by multiple businesses (tenants). There is a single mobile app for these customers. Once they login, they should be able to get services from any tenant unless a tenant has blocked a user.

Note that the point here is these customers are NOT registering for each tenant separately.

What are my options to get this setup done properly using AspNetBoilerplate? My initial thoughts are;

1) Have a separate table - MyCustomers - All mobile users will get authenticated against this table. For this should i create a separate auth pipeline ?

2) Current AspNetBoilerplate demo; you choose the tenant and login. But in my case; they log in and they will choose a service provider (tenant).  At this point;

1. Should I create a new user automatically IF the selected tenant is in a different database (For large businesses having their own database)?
2. If the selected service provider is a small customer, who are in the same database differentiated with a TenantId I will have to additionally have a  --> (many)  relationship maintained so when a new service is selected a new record goes to this table?

At the end of the day, MyCustomers will only be using a single mobile app to get any service from any business after they login. Once they login, they should have access to all tenants (unless they are blocked).

Is there a better way to do this using AspNetBoilerplate existing architecture?

Comment: If your tenants are providing various services to the customer, then are you managing those tenants? If the customers are not registered to your tenants, are they registered under your identity service? You can consider running one abp project (A) as a identity service then another abp project (B) to run multi tenancy and using (A) as an external authentication provider for (B).  And modify the authentication code on (B) to allow any customer from (A) to use the various services.

Comment: I assume that some misunderstanding has happened, multi-tenancy architecture is to gain data-encapsulation. But in ABP there are some facilities regarding the editions and their features. According to your issue, which customers need to be shared in all tenants, multi-tenancy architecture may not help you.

Comment: i create tenants and tenant can manage their own services. ex:- I create Tenant A. Then Tenant A admin creates 2 branches. clients select TenantA -> Select a branch to obtain any services provided by that branch... What is the advantage you see in having two projects as oppose to a separate global Customer table for all tenants? multi-tenancy have use here because each tenant has it's own data isolated

Comment: @user2058413 I have the same scenario did you found a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Well... I haven't started working on it yet since another task became priority. But my plan is to go with my suggested option (1), have a custom set of rules to bypass tenant filtering as needed so allowed sets of data can still be read from any tenant (service providers)... should work without an issue....